# Shutil saves a file as File type and not .txt

Tags: python, shutil

I am using the following code to join a few .txt files to one file using Shutil. The saved file is saved as a 'File' format, but I can open it with Notepad. How can I save the file to .txt directly?

```
    #Join generated text files to one file
    import shutil
    with open(img_file,'wb') as wfd:
        for f in out_file_list:
            with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```

Comment: I believe while naming it you can just write .txt at the end of the name and it saves it as .txt but I haven't worked with shutil so...

Comment: have a look at Pythons [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for path and filename handling in general.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @FoundAbetterName works as intended. Thank you!

```
    #Join generated text files to one file
    import shutil
    with open(img_file + ".txt",'wb') as wfd:
        for f in out_file_list:
            with open(f,'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```